# OOP problem: Relationship between category, sub category and product

Tags: php, class, oop, composition

I am now using PHP, try to do a exercise myself for studying but encounter a problem currently.

My design is like: 1 **Category** will contains 0 to many **Sub Category**, and 1 **Sub Category** will contains 0 to many **Product**, Each **Product** in my case will only belongs to 1 **SubCategory**. In my view, they are composition relationship(please correct me if wrong), But after that I don't know how to write the code of this kind of relationship. In my view, it should be 3 classes (**Category,SubCategory,Product**) with their own attributes and method. But may be due to my mind is still stuck in my design page. I will create a page for adding a new Category and its SubCategory(of course it will also have another page for editing and updating). And create a page for adding a new Product.

If I write the code of **Category** and **SubCatgory** like that, how about the class **Product**? What I am stucking is, if I write the class **Product** like that, but I already put the attribute [product] in class **SubCategory**, isn't be a wrong logic? Can anyone tell me a proper logic for designing this relationship?  I know for many seniors it may be a stupid question, but it really stucks me for a month without a proper solution.

Moreover, is that any advice or materials for teaching how to design a good class structure and relationship? I think this is really hard for me.

Thank you for viewing my question.

```
Class Category{
private $subCat;

public function createNewSubCat(){
$this->subCat[]=new SubCategory();
}
}

Class SubCategory{
private $product;
public function createNewProduct(){
$this->product[]=new Product();
}
}

Class Product{
private $cat;
private $subCat;

public function setCategory(Category $c){
$this->cat=$c;
}

public function setSubCat(SubCategory $subC){
$this->subCat=$subC;
}
}
```

Comment: You are including links both ways: from the **SubCatgory** to the **Product** and visa versa. That's fine. You current code is very rudimentary however, it needs to be fleshed out a lot more. `createNewProduct()` should use `product->setSubCat()` method and return the newly created product. And so on. Also, your **Category** and **SubCatgory** objects will be very similar, they're both categories, why not make them the same? That would allow you to have as many levels of categories as you need.

Comment: Don't set both the category and the subcategory on a product. The subcategory implies the category, so just set the subcategory. And, in the subcategory, I would add the category.

Comment: @KIKO Software Could you please give me more detail about make Category and SubCategory  object to the same class and implement it? Or could you please tell me where can I learn these kinds of concept?

I really get frustrated of defining class, but I don't know where can I get knowledge of that.

Answer (score 0):

You could merge the **Category** and **SubCatgory** classes into one **Category** class. Like this:

```
class Category
{
    private $parentCategory = NULL;
    private $categoryLevel = 0;
    private $categories = [];
    private $products = [];

    public function __construct($parentCategory = NULL)
    {
        if ($parentCategory) {
            $this->parentCategory = $parentCategory;
            $this->categoryLevel = $parentCategory->getCategoryLevel() + 1;
        }
    }

    public function getCategoryLevel()
    {
        return $this->categoryLevel;
    }

    public function createNewCategory()
    {
        return $this->categories[] = new Category($this);
    }

    public function createNewProduct(){
        return $this->products[] = new Product($this);
    }
}

class Product
{
    private $parentCategory;

    public function __construct($parentCategory = NULL)
    {
        $this->parentCategory = $parentCategory;
    }
}
```

Note that I wrote this loosely typed for simplicity, but I added a "level" attribute to the category class, so you can check how deep in the tree a specific category is.

As you can see there's no reason to have a "SubCategory" class. This simplifies your code, especially when you want to render the categories.

Note how I connect sub-categories and products using the constructor.

You could put in a restriction: When a category class has child category it cannot have a product, and when it has a product it cannot have a child category. Alternatively, you could allow this.

Finally, one thing you need to *unlearn as quickly as possible*: Abbreviating things that should not be abbreviated. A "category" is a "category", it's not a "cat", which is an animal, nor is it "c", whatever that means. Use meaningful names that reflect the content of a variable. Shorter names are not always better names, especially if they are ambiguous, nor do longer names slow down the execution of your code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment, I will try to modify the code for further development. One more question, could you please tell me where can I learn of design the system of defining class? Actually I read some books about system development, UML, but every time I try to practice, I have no idea who can ask that without a detail example. PHP programming books can not teach you how to make a good design of class creation, I always get stuck so I can not write a better code and thus hard to maintenance my code.

Comment: @Saxon I learned it by practicing a lot, and by looking at other code. I'm not a guy for much theory, but some people find that useful. For instance the [SOLID principles](https://accesto.com/blog/solid-php-solid-principles-in-php) teach you some basic rules. However, none of those book and principles can tell you exactly how to model a new domain in classes. That's where your experience and creativity as a programmer comes in. Never be afraid to rewrite code several times when you think you can do better.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I don't afraid to rewriting code for improve my skill, but I didn't see the path how to improve, that is the problem. You said looking other code and I did, but sometimes the scale of other project is large and hard to learn from it, that's why I stuck.